# Facing issue while deploying iOS app to app store in Visual Studio

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-community

I am new to iOS Development using Xamarin, I am trying to upload my iOS app to app store, however i am getting the below error:

[Error while publishing app to app store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07qrQ.png)

[No Validate Option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYdzl.png)

I have tried using different architecture however the issue is not resolved.

Answer (score 0):

According your Issues (image you have provide).

**At First,** most easiest solution for your warning is, you need to include additional icon of `1024x1024pt` size in **Assets.xcassets**.

And then follow the below steps -

1. Go to `Assets.xcassets.`
2. Drag and drop the icon of `1024*1024p`t in App Store iOS `1024pt` field of `Assets.xcassets`

**Secondly,** for you error- you can try below options for the Apps that include an `arm64` architecture are required to include an `armv7` architecture-

1. You can run the app on your phone with the usb cord plugged into the computer.
2. Unplug your phone, when the app has successfully played on your phone.
3. Go to **product > archive > validate**
4. Click submit to app store when you have done this and your app should submit just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, could you please let me know where is the validate option in visual studio 2015, I do see it in xcode but not in visual studio

Comment: @ShyamalDhinoja Please see this - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eQ7ZrHA4E_o

Comment: Thanks for the video, I saw it however there was no validate option in my visual studio, Here is the screenshot for the same: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYdzl.png. I have resolved my issue now it seems that armv7s was the issue, I have removed it from supported architectures and it worked. Thanks for the help

Comment: @ShyamalDhinoja   Welcome bro.. :)